# c - some problem with byte xor

Tags: c, xor

I have to make some binary xor on 2 byte buffers. one is an encoding key, the other the encoded value.

at the moment my code looks like this:

```
BYTE key[]={"somekey"}
BYTE value[]={"somevalue"};

for(i= 0; i < vallLength; i++)
    {
        valBuf[i] = value[i] ^ key[i % keyLength];
    }
```

this does not work for me. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Who is vallLength? I think we need more code...

Comment: What do you mean by "this does not work for me"? What happens that you don't expect? What do you expect to happen instead?

Comment: what does the "^" operator does? Do i get the entire BYTE masked?

Comment: valLength the the length of the value...

Comment: check if `i % keyLength` causes overflow for `key`.

Comment: What is the result? What did you expect the result to be?

Comment: @aaaa: You have to either answer my questions above, post a complete program (that compiles), or both. Preferably, both. Until you do that, the only answers you'll get will be guesses.

Comment: you need to add a `';'` to the definition of `key`; otherwise, with the less changes I could do, [your code works as you've posted](http://ideone.com/zsFID).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, this is terrible, but I felt like writing some easy code for a change.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char key[] = "This is a fancy key.";
char text[] = "Encrypt this extremely long plaintext.";
#define KEY_LEN (sizeof(key))
#define TXT_LEN (sizeof(text))

void crypt(char *key, char *plaintext, char *ciphertext, int keyLen, int ptLen)
{    
    int idx;
    for (idx = 0; idx < ptLen; idx++)
    {
        ciphertext[idx] = plaintext[idx] ^ key[idx % keyLen];
    }
}

int main()
{
    printf("Plaintext before:\n\t%s\n", text);
    crypt(key, text, text, KEY_LEN, TXT_LEN);
    printf("Plaintext after:\n\t%s\n", text);
    crypt(key, text, text, KEY_LEN, TXT_LEN);
    printf("Plaintext after after:\n\t%s\n", text);
    return 0;
}
```

This question's destined for closure anyway, so it can't hurt too much to post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Are the arrays "key" and "value" the same length?  I'm not sure of the result you are looking for, but you might want to ONLY loop over the shorter length, then pad the longer array values to the ^ answer.

```
BYTE* xx = new BYTE[SIZEX];
BYTE* yy = new BYTE[SIZEY];

int nCount = Min(xx.Length(), yy.Length());
BYTE* answer = new BYTE[Max(xx.Length(), yy.Length())];
for(int ii=0; ii<nCount; ++ii)
    answer[ii] = xx[ii] ^ y[ii];

BYTE* zz;
if(xx.Length() > yy.Length())
    zz = xx;
else
    zz = yy;

for(int ii=nCount; ii<Max(xx.Length(), yy.Length()); ++ii)
    answer[ii] = zz[ii];
```

Comment: That's what the modulo is there for.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure if he wanted '%' because he hasn't defined why it doesn't work yet.  I was just trying to guess.  If he knows they are both two byte arrarys, why use '%'?

Comment: The code in the question is the standard way to implement a XOR cipher. The code in your answer doesn't make sense, as it will leave some of the input unencrypted.

Comment: +1 - thanks!  I clearly didn't see where he was going with this.  I learned something -- is it more common to "%" the extra values, or just set them all to "0" or "1"?

Comment: The `%` essentially makes the key repeat itself, until it's the same length as the input text. This ensures that the whole text is encrypted (though it's a weak form of encryption).

Answer (score -3):

It could be because "i % keyLength" is undefined for the first run of your loop as i=0

Comment: I beg to differ: `i % keyLength` is very well defined for i = 0: the result is 0 for all non-zero keyLength.

Comment: This is a valid answer if he deletes "for the first run of... ".  It's hard to tell, but maybe keyLength is the issue.